# JQuery и GET переменная

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, get

Есть урл, типа:

> disci.php?firm=Slick&razmer=4&radius=15&pcd1=5&pcd2=100&dia=60&tip=1&color=Black&sort=1&now_p=1

Как установить свои селекторы (select) в значения из этих GET переменных?

Cпасибо всем, вот моя реализация:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return(false);
}

$('#firm').val(getQueryVariable('firm'));
$('#razmer').val(getQueryVariable('razmer'));
$('#radius').val(getQueryVariable('radius'));
$('#pcd1').val(getQueryVariable('pcd1'));
$('#pcd2').val(getQueryVariable('pcd2'));
$('#dia').val(getQueryVariable('dia'));
$('#tip').val(getQueryVariable('tip'));
$('#color').val(getQueryVariable('color'));
$('#sort').val(getQueryVariable('sort'));
```

Или может есть более простой способ установить селекторы в прежнее положение после перегрузки страницы по get\post переменным?

Так-то есть вариант обрабатывать это всё php, но мне кажется что это будет глупо.

Comment: Неужели только парсить явой URL? Не хотелось бы совсем...

Comment: @Олег Б причем здесь java ? и почему-бы прям в той php не выставить селекторы в нужные значения атрибутом `select` ?

Comment: Лист селекторов генерируется 1 раз когда чтотоменяется в SQL и вставляется Includ'ом, нет возможности генерить селекторы на "лету". Мне нужно устанавливать лишь их в selected явой, как я думаю.....

Comment: **причем здесь ява ?**
---

[тут два способа удобных](http://stackoverflow.com/a/439578/815386)

Comment: Но этим объектам SELECTED-то я сделаю только явой!??

Comment: eicto, простите я наверно понял ваш пост :)